# Getting some problem with apply event to dynamic added form in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am loading the form in dialog box via jQuery

The code is like

```
<form class ="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
...
</form>
```

I am using jQuery form plugin to submit form  like this

```
$(".form1").live('submit', function(e) {   

    var options = { 
        target:        '.ajaxMessage',  
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  
        success:       showResponse,
        type: 'POST'

    }; 
    alert('test');                          
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
    return false;                                         
});
```

Now

1. If i load the form directly without AJAX and then i submit the form then form gets submiited successfuly without any problem. It works 10 out of 10 times
2. In second case I load the form dynamically. When i click on form link then i load the form dynamically in a jquery dialog box then if i click on submit form then i can see the alert but form is not submitted. But it works sometimes but sometimes not. I would say it work 2 times out of 10.

Firebug console is also not showing any error

Is there any way i can find whats problem

Answer (score 0):

Firebug will usually (I actually think not at all) won't show any errors for a ajax call, instead the error will be in the ajax request(still in firebug). Click the request and then response.

My guess is that there is a problem with the params you are sending or there is something wrong with what you a returning(i.e. you return html when ajax is expecting json, this will cause success never to be fired)

Also, try to pass an `error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}` to the ` ajaxSubmit params and see what happens.

Comment: Are the responses in firebug the exact same same between the page load and when you call it from click? and Is there some more code you can share or even a link?